# How do I umount device that has been mounted twice

Tags: linux, umount

I have a `/dev/sdf` mounted to `/mnt/db` and accidentally mounted it again to /mnt/db2 (I intended to mount `/dev/sdh`).

Is there any way to umount `/dev/sdf` but only for the 2nd mount?  The `/mnt/db` contains live databases, so I'd rather not have have any down time.

Answer (score 9):

You can specify the directory that has the mount:

```
umount /mnt/db2
```

The man page for `umount` mentions unmounting from the directory explicitly. It says it is the best way to do it, and that it works if you've mounted the device more than once.

> Giving  the  special device on which the file system lives may also work, but is obsolete, mainly because it will fail in case this device was mounted on more than one directory.